# Using jquery.load() function to load an angular page

Tags: php, html, angularjs, iframe, jquery-load

im working in a personal project right now and im mixing jquery and angularjs
and this week i face one problem that is the next

what im trying to do is load an angular page into a div using jquery.load()

(jquery part)
Test1.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="sss" type="button">load angular page into div using jquery</button>

<div id="tarkan"></div>
<script>
    $("#sss").on("click", function (e) { 
        $("#tarkan").load("/elements/test2.php");   
    });
</script>
```

(angular part)
test2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
                    {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function (response) {
                  $scope.myData = response.data.records;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the test1.php gives me this

```
{{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
```

instead the data of the angular page.

today my partial solution to this is the use of iframes instead of using jquery.load

```
<div id="tarkan"></div>
<iframe id="tarkan2" src="" width="100%" height="700px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
<script>
    $("#sss").on("click", function (e) { 
        //its not working
        $("#tarkan").load("/elements/test2.php");
        //its working   
        $("#tarkan2").attr("src", "/elements/test2.php");
    });
</script>
```

my final question is there a way to load the angularpage into a div using jquery load?
any explanations or solutions are very welcome :)

Comment: do you have to use jquery? Can you not create a directive for test2.php and load it on button click?

Comment: You already loaded angularjs on your initial page. So why you don't use it to load the template you need?

Comment: @Y.Hewa of course that have to use jquery, and yes i can create a directive taken from the answer made it by you. but my original question it was "is there a way to load the angularpage into a div using jquery load?" but thanks for your solution :) is very welcome. by you i know how the templateURL works now.

Comment: @xReeQz i loaded the angularjs script in the initial page in an attempt to once the angular page is loaded the angularjs script of the initial page works in the loaded code.but It seems to not be working or im not understanding how the events works very well

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this with only angular : by using directive for the data and have a button click in the controller that would load the directive .. the directive is shown only if the $scope.show is true.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);



app.controller('Mycontroller', function($scope) {

   $scope.show = false;
  $scope.getData = function() {
    console.log("hi");
    $scope.show = true;
  };

})


      app.directive('customersCtrl', function() {
         return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $http) {


    $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data.records;
      });
    },
    templateUrl: 'test2.tpl.html'
  }
});
```

here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vOCMXOQaSQuoG6CwTIZI?p=preview)

Comment: it seems to be the fully angular solution to what im trying to achieve but as i said before my original answer was "is there a way to load the angularpage into a div using jquery load? "

Comment: Is there a specific reason why your mixing jQuery and AngularJS? In your case , as far as i know its best to stick to Angular approach, and the reason your code isnt working is because once you load the page in jquery the angular doesnt know about it therefore it won't work..

Comment: "Is there a specific reason why your mixing jQuery and AngularJS?" 
yes there is and specific reason: learning if works so well as i expected under my testing porpouses.
and this is what i expected as an answer: "and the reason your code isnt working is because once you load the page in jquery the angular doesnt know about it therefore it won't work.." :).